# Why was Darui sucked into the Benihisago?

Tags: naruto, japanese-language

In episode 269 of Naruto, while fighting Kinkaku and Ginkaku, Daru got sucked into the Benihisago. I thought you could only be sucked in if you said your most said word or if you remained silent. Darui did neither, but was sucked in after he said "I'm the Boss' right arm. I'm no imitation!" Does this sound like his most said word, "dull," in Japanese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from the [Naruto wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Darui), 'he inadvertently uttered the word when he admonished the brothers and stated, "Ore wa Bosu no migiude **da. Ru**ijihin janē! (「オレはボスの右腕だ。類似品じゃねェ!」, I'm the Boss' right arm. I'm no imitation!)"'. "Daru" sounds like his most said word, "darui."
This is why he was sealed.

Comment: The "i" is there, too. 類 reads "rui", so the end of the first sentence and the beginning of the second give exactly "darui".

Answer (score 3):

In the English version he says " I am not a timid rabbit", his word was "Drab". Thus when he utters timi**D RAB**bit, the word drab is said.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.